I am getting an error bottom navigation bar Widget in flutter
I am having this error:

══════ Exception caught by widgets library
═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
6750 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by widgets library
═══════════════════════════════════ Duplicate GlobalKey detected in
widget tree.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

and the navigation bar is not working it is not direct me to the pages that I want and it keeps lagging. Can anyone help me I've seen lot of YouTube videos but I didn't see what's the problem.
Navigation bar code:
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Screens/categories.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Screens/myReports.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBarWidget> createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarWidgetState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarWidgetState extends State<BottomNavigationBarWidget> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  void _nav(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final screen = [Categories(), const MyReports()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GNav(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 235, 197),
      activeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 135, 135),
      color: Colors.white,
      gap: 3,
      selectedIndex: currentIndex,
      onTabChange: _nav,
      tabs: [
        GButton(
          icon: Icons.home,
          text: 'Home',
        ),
        GButton(
          icon: Icons.notifications,
          text: 'My Reports',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Report page:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Controller/ReportsController.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Widgets/bottomNavBar.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Widgets/drawer.dart';

class MyReports extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyReports({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyReports> createState() => _MyReportsState();
}

final controller = Get.put(ReportsController());

class _MyReportsState extends State<MyReports> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFF5EA),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('My Reports'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: controller.viewCurrentReports(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Center(child: Text("Error fetching reports"));
            } else {
              if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(
                    child: Text("You don't have any reports yet"));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final items = snapshot.data!;
                    return Dismissible(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      background: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.delete,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      secondaryBackground: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                          controller.deleteReport(items[index]["report_id"]);
                        } else if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                          //edit item stuff
                        }
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(184, 211, 207, 207),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(items[index]['report_type']),
                          subtitle: Text(items[index]['incident_description']),
                          onTap: () {
                            // Handle tapping on the card
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            }
          }
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarWidget(),
    );
  }
}

Categories page:
// ignore_for_file: sized_box_for_whitespace

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Screens/AddReport.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Widgets/bottomNavBar.dart';
import 'package:notify_ju/Widgets/drawer.dart';

class Categories extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> image = [
    'images/fight123.jpg',
    'images/fiire.webp',
    'images/carss.png',
    'images/doggg.png',
    'images/injuryy.png',
    'images/infraa.png',
  ];

  final List<String> names = [
    'Fight',
    'Fire',
    'Car Accident',
    'Stray Animals',
    'Injury',
    'Infrastructure Damage',
  ];

  Categories({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFF5EA),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Choose a Category',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 235, 197),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: List.generate(
                image.length,
                (index) => Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => addReport(
                            reportType: names[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Container(
                          height: 110,
                          child: Image.asset(image[index],
                              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                              scale: 1.0,
                              alignment: Alignment.center),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15),
                        Text(names[index],
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarWidget(),
    );
  }
}

